# AngularJS ng-pattern throws error on regex for phone number

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, ng-pattern

I'm using ng-pattern on a text field to validate a Canadian phone number:

```
^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$
```

But AngularJS throws this error:

> Syntax Error: Token '?' not a primary expression at column 3 of the expression [^(?([0-9]{3}))?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$] starting at [?([0-9]{3}))?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$].

I tested it, and tried it in a couple different online regex editors like [Rubular](http://rubular.com/), and it seems perfectly valid.  I am creating the fields dynamically so ng-pattern is being set like this in the directive within ngRepeat.

```
ng-pattern="{{field.format}}"
```

if I change it to hardcoded regex it doesn't throw any errors:

```
ng-pattern="/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/"
```

But then I changed it to something ridiculously simple:

```
^[0-9]{3}$
```

And this works, so can't be dynamically created fields and related to just the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bonjour. The first `?` doesn't have anything to quantify. Remove it. Which means that you also should remove the resulting extra parenthesis.

`^([0-9]{3})?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$`

Ed. With optional brackets (actually parenthesis) for area code (untested):

`^(\(?([0-9]{3})\)?)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$`

Comment: thought that it would allow me to have brackets on the area code, so escaped them so it wasn't a grouping and added ? for 0 or 1 instances.  you're solution does work, but how would you add the brackets?

Comment: Thanks, I just replaced the [] with ().  I see what I was doing wrong.